# Convert iOS UISegmentControl to type CFTimeInterval

Tags: swift, casting

Using Swift 3, I had a hard-coded value in this statement:

```
var lastDisplayLinkTimeStamp: CFTimeInterval!

 if self.lastDisplayLinkTimeStamp >= 30
 {
    totalTimes += 1
  }
```

But now I've set up a segment control to let the user select 30.0, 45.0, or 60.0 as the value instead of the hardcoded value.

I know I can get the text of the title of the selected segment using this:

```
durationSegment.titleForSegment(at: durationSegment.selectedSegmentIndex
```

which I think produces a String? (optional String)

But how do I convert the durationSegment.titleForSegment of the text to be accepted in the if statement as a CFTimeInterval or I think Double is also accepted?

I've tried several variations of this using a CFTimeInterval or Double or Float cast

```
 if self.lastDisplayLinkTimeStamp >= Double(durationSegment.titleForSegment(at: durationSegment.selectedSegmentIndex)
 {
    totalTimes += 1
  }
```

but still get an error like:

> Binary operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'CFTimeInterval!' and 'Double?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the title of the segments. The titles are for display purposes and should not represent your data.

One solution is to create an array of time intervals:

```
let possibleTimeIntervals: [CFTimeInterval] = [ 30.0, 45.0, 60.0 ]
```

Then get the value based on the selected segment:

```
let selectedSegment = durationSegment.selectedSegmentIndex
if selectedSegment != UISegmentedControlNoSegment {
    let timeInterval = possibleTimeIntervals[selectedSegment]
    if self.lastDisplayLinkTimeStamp >= timeInterval {
        totalTimes += 1
    }
}
```

BTW - you can even use the `possibleTimeIntervals` array to create the segment titles using a number formatter.

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting an error Use of Undeclared type 'CFTimeInterval' for this line: let possibleTimeIntervals: [CFTimerInterval] = [ 30.0, 45.0, 60.0 ]. I do have QuartzCore imported. Where would I put this line - after the class declaration as an instance variable?

Comment: Obviously that was supposed to be `CFTimeInterval`, not `CFTimerInterval`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine. And I will implement your suggestion about using number formatter to create segment titles dynamically, I was think of something like that as well. Thanks again for your help.